# Unable to Connect to SQL Server in Docker Container from Local Machine Despite Successful Dockerized Application Connection

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerized application that successfully connects to a SQL Server instance running within the same Docker network. However, I'm unable to connect to the SQL Server from my local machine. I've tried various troubleshooting steps without success.

Docker Compose Configuration:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  my-service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myshop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My-Shop/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - my-shop-db
    networks:
      - my-network

  my-shop-db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: "Secure-Password"
      MSSQL_PID: Express
    ports:
      - "1433:1433" 
    volumes:
      - mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql 
    networks:
      - my-network

volumes:
  mssql-data: # Define the named volume for MSSQL Server data persistence
    driver: local

networks:
  my-network:
```

Connection String:

```
"MyShopContext": "Server=my-shop-db,1433;Initial Catalog=MyShopDb;User ID=sa;Password=Secure-Password;"
```

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including checking the network mode, verifying the correct server name, ensuring the correct port mapping, checking firewall settings, and inspecting the Docker network. Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to connect to the SQL Server instance from my local machine.

I am using server name as `my-shop-db`
login username as `sa`
and password as `Secure-Password`

and getting the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to ?>SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name ?>is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named >Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Framework Microsoft >SqlClient Data Provider)

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's `my-shop-db`?  From your local machine use the IP of the Docker host.

Comment: it's just a servername of the sql.

Comment: I run this command in my local machine `docker network inspect bridge --format "{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}"` and gave me the following ip `172.17.0.1`.

and use this ip as a servername in sql server management studio, and got the same error. @Pino

Comment: Not `docker network` but `ip addr`.  The name `my-shop-db` is not in your docker-compose.

Comment: I also did `ipconfig` on my local machine because it is windows, and use the ip and got the same error.

Comment: Aside... not the cause of your problem, but the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable is deprecated and will soon stop working. You should switch to `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` as per [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

Comment: The `my-shop-db` name will only be resolved for Docker containers in the composition (it's Docker's internal DNS that resolves it). That's why `my-shop-db` can't be used when connecting from processes on the Docker host. `172.17.0.1` is also a non-routable address on a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) that only works inside the Docker container network. When connecting from the Docker host itself have you tried using `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `::1` instead?

Comment: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `::1` nothing among them works when I put that on the connection strings, couldn't connect to database...`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible....` same error @AlwaysLearning

Comment: I just noticed "Named Pipes Provider" in the error message. That only works for Windows-based SQL Server instances. Can you try forcing the client to use the TCP/IP protocol with `Server=tcp:localhost,1433;...` in your connection string?

Comment: Yes I just tried changing the server, but it didn't connect to the database, got the exception with same error.